# Custom parameter binding attributes in aspnet Core with OData

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have an implementation of Ricks "raw request body" attribute blogged about here ...

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api

... i'm in the process of converting the solution to .Net Core ...

Does anyone know how to achieve this in aspNet Core as a binding attribute on OData controller parameters?

EDIT:

In case it helps anyone, here's the code i'm trying to convert ...

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Core.Api
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An attribute that captures the entire content body and stores it
    /// into the parameter of type byte[].
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The parameter marked up with this attribute should be the only parameter as it reads the
    /// entire request body and assigns it to that parameter.    
    /// </remarks>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class RawBodyAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
    {
        public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
        {
            if (parameter == null) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameter");
            return new RawBodyParameterBinding(parameter);
        }
    }

    public class RawBodyParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
    {
        public RawBodyParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor) : base(descriptor) { }

        public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var binding = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionBinding;
            if(binding.ParameterBindings.Count(pb => pb.GetType() == typeof(RawBodyParameterBinding)) != 1)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Exactly one parameter must be marked with the RawBody attribute in the action signature.");

            var type = binding.ParameterBindings.First(pb => pb.GetType() == typeof(RawBodyParameterBinding)).Descriptor.ParameterType;

            if (type == typeof(string))
            {
                return actionContext.Request.Content
                        .ReadAsStringAsync()
                        .ContinueWith((task) => SetValue(actionContext, task.Result));
            }
            else if(type == typeof(byte[]))
            {
                return actionContext.Request.Content
                    .ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
                    .ContinueWith((task) => SetValue(actionContext, task.Result));
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only byte[] or string values are supported for [RawBody] parameters");
        }

        public override bool WillReadBody
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implmenet your own attribute and binder.

1. `RawBodyAttribute`

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
   public class RawBodyAttribute : Attribute, IBindingSourceMetadata
   {
       public BindingSource BindingSource => RawBodyBindingSource.RawBody;
   }
   ```
2. `RawBodyBindingSource`

   ```
   public class RawBodyBindingSource : BindingSource
   {
       public static readonly BindingSource RawBody = new RawBodyBindingSource(
           "RawBody",
           "RawBody",
           true,
           true
       );

       public RawBodyBindingSource(string id, string displayName, bool isGreedy, bool isFromRequest) 
           : base(id, displayName, isGreedy, isFromRequest)
       {
       }

       public override bool CanAcceptDataFrom(BindingSource bindingSource)
       {
           return bindingSource == Body || bindingSource == this;
       }
   }
   ```
3. `RawBodyModelBinder`

   ```
   public class RawBodyModelBinder : IModelBinder
   {
       public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
       {           

           using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
           {
               var model = reader.ReadToEnd();
               bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
           }

           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }
   }
   ```
4. `RawBodyModelBinderProvider`

   ```
   public class RawBodyModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
   {
       public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
       {
           if (context.BindingInfo.BindingSource != null
               && context.BindingInfo.BindingSource.CanAcceptDataFrom(RawBodyBindingSource.RawBody))
           {
               return new RawBodyModelBinder();
           }
           else
           {
               return null;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Register

   ```
   services.AddMvc(options =>
   {
       options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new RawBodyModelBinderProvider());
   }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   ```
6. Use Case

   ```
   public IActionResult Post([RawBody]string value)
   {
       return Ok(value);
   }
   ```

Comment: Only microsoft could make something better by requiring a dev to write more code than the previous version. This is brutal!

Comment: Turns out you can straight up just read the Request Body in the controller action which would save all that ... that's nice at least ... do you know if this approach would work for file sends though Tao?